# Jbehave given stories

Tags: selenium, jbehave

I am using jbehave using selenium. Whenever there is a failure in story, the story gets hanged up , even though the step is failed, the browser also doesnot closes.

Please find my configuration :

```
return new SeleniumConfiguration()
            .useWebDriverProvider(driverProvider)
            .useSeleniumContext(seleniumContext).useFailureStrategy(new FailingUponPendingStep())
            .useStoryControls(new StoryControls().doResetStateBeforeScenario(false).doIgnoreMetaFiltersIfGivenStory(true))
            //.useStepMonitor(new SeleniumStepMonitor(contextView, seleniumContext, xref.getStepMonitor())) //?
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass().getClassLoader()))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new MyStoryReporterBuilder(config, storyData, props, dbConnection)
                    .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromPath(getClassPath()))
                    .withDefaultFormats()
                    .withCrossReference(xref)
                    .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.HTML, Format.XML))
            ;
}
```

Comment: The story fails at a certain step but the browser doesnot close and the story doesnot end. In a story which I am running I have three Given stories,separated by comma .

Comment: Very nice, good for you.